# CSS: Why does a 1px border render as 1.111px?

Tags: html, css, size, width, border

I don't understand why the caseButtonBarRow2 div width rendered as 297.778px.  It should be 300px, right?  I *think* it's my `border: 1px #FF2F2A solid;`.  That appears to be rendered with a size of 1.111px....but why?  This is several div levels deep in a container with a fixed width of 310px (padding left/right is 5px).  The top level div is the only div with a fixed width, so I *guess* caseButtonBarRow2 should stretch to 300px even, right?

HTML:

```
<div id="caseButtonBarRow2" class="buttonBarRow">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <a id="MainContent_Case7CheckBox_ToggleButton" href="" title="UNSELECTED" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px; font-size: 40px; background-image: url(https://jimasta-laptop/ExaminerGradeSheet/images/ExaminerButton7_unchecked.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></a>
    </div>
    <input data-act-togglebuttonextender="imageWidth:40,imageHeight:40,uncheckedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton7_unchecked.png',checkedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton_checked.png',uncheckedImageAlternateText:'UNSELECTED',checkedImageAlternateText:'Case 7',id:'MainContent_ctl230'" id="MainContent_Case7CheckBox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Case7CheckBox" style="visibility: hidden;">

    <div style="position: relative;"><a id="MainContent_Case8CheckBox_ToggleButton" href="" title="UNSELECTED" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px; font-size: 40px; background-image: url(https://jimasta-laptop/ExaminerGradeSheet/images/ExaminerButton8_unchecked.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;">

        </a>
    </div>
    <input data-act-togglebuttonextender="imageWidth:40,imageHeight:40,uncheckedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton8_unchecked.png',checkedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton_checked.png',uncheckedImageAlternateText:'UNSELECTED',checkedImageAlternateText:'Case 8',id:'MainContent_ctl232'" id="MainContent_Case8CheckBox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Case8CheckBox" style="visibility: hidden;">

    <div style="position: relative;">
        <a id="MainContent_Case9CheckBox_ToggleButton" href="" title="UNSELECTED" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px; font-size: 40px; background-image: url(https://jimasta-laptop/ExaminerGradeSheet/images/ExaminerButton9_unchecked.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        </a>
    </div>
    <input data-act-togglebuttonextender="imageWidth:40,imageHeight:40,uncheckedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton9_unchecked.png',checkedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton_checked.png',uncheckedImageAlternateText:'UNSELECTED',checkedImageAlternateText:'Case 9',id:'MainContent_ctl234'" id="MainContent_Case9CheckBox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Case9CheckBox" style="visibility: hidden;">

    <div style="position: relative;">
        <a id="MainContent_Case10CheckBox_ToggleButton" href="" title="UNSELECTED" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px; font-size: 40px; background-image: url(https://jimasta-laptop/ExaminerGradeSheet/images/ExaminerButton10_unchecked.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        </a>
    </div>
    <input data-act-togglebuttonextender="imageWidth:40,imageHeight:40,uncheckedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton10_unchecked.png',checkedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton_checked.png',uncheckedImageAlternateText:'UNSELECTED',checkedImageAlternateText:'Case 10',id:'MainContent_ctl236'" id="MainContent_Case10CheckBox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Case10CheckBox" style="visibility: hidden;">

    <div style="position: relative;">
        <a id="MainContent_Case11CheckBox_ToggleButton" href="" title="UNSELECTED" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px; font-size: 40px; background-image: url(https://jimasta-laptop/ExaminerGradeSheet/images/ExaminerButton11_unchecked.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        </a>
    </div>
    <input data-act-togglebuttonextender="imageWidth:40,imageHeight:40,uncheckedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton11_unchecked.png',checkedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton_checked.png',uncheckedImageAlternateText:'UNSELECTED',checkedImageAlternateText:'Case 11',id:'MainContent_ctl238'" id="MainContent_Case11CheckBox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Case11CheckBox" style="visibility: hidden;">

    <div style="position: relative;">
        <a id="MainContent_Case12CheckBox_ToggleButton" href="" title="UNSELECTED" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px; font-size: 40px; background-image: url(https://jimasta-laptop/ExaminerGradeSheet/images/ExaminerButton12_unchecked.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        </a>
    </div>
    <input data-act-togglebuttonextender="imageWidth:40,imageHeight:40,uncheckedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton12_unchecked.png',checkedImageUrl:'images/ExaminerButton_checked.png',uncheckedImageAlternateText:'UNSELECTED',checkedImageAlternateText:'Case 12',id:'MainContent_ctl240'" id="MainContent_Case12CheckBox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Case12CheckBox" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.buttonBar > div:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.buttonBar > div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.buttonBarRow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
    display: block;
}
Pseudo ::before element
    * , *:before, *:after {
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
Pseudo ::after element
    * , *:before, *:after {
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
Inherited from div#caseButtonBar.buttonBar
    .buttonBar {
        margin: 5px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
Inherited from div.gradeSheetFont
    .gradeSheetFont {
        font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FF2F2A;
    }
Inherited from body
    body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.428571429;
        color: #333333;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
Inherited from html.js.flexbox.flexboxlegacy.canvas.canvastext.webgl.no-touch.geolocation.postmessage.websqldatabase.indexeddb.hashchange.history.draganddrop.websockets.rgba.hsla.multiplebgs.backgroundsize.borderimage.borderradius.boxshadow.textshadow.opacity.cssanimations.csscolumns.cssgradients.cssreflections.csstransforms.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.fontface.generatedcontent.video.audio.localstorage.sessionstorage.webworkers.applicationcache.svg.inlinesvg.smil.svgclippaths
    html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
       -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
   -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Could you post all containing divs if there is more? Can't see what buttonBarRow2 class actually contains

Comment: Did you zoom your page to 90%? Press CTRL+0 and check again.

Comment: Show your *actual* HTML and CSS code. Explain what makes you think 1px is implemented as something. If you include stuff from a browser’s dev tools, separate them from your own code and identify where you copied them from.

Comment: ...and what does 0.111px look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry it took so long to update this question.  Thanks ***@SalmanA***!  You were correct.  I was (inadvertently) viewing the page at 90%.

***To note:*** the Chrome Dev Tools **"Computed Box"** will show the ***rendered*** size of any element. That means even though the border is **1px**, it will show in the **"Computed"** panel as **1.111px** if you're viewing the page at 90%.

I made the mistake of thinking the **"Computed"** panel would show the ***declared*** style attributes of the element selected rather than the ***rendered*** style attributes.  Confusing, I think, but whatever.